# System.ObjectDisposedException when closing a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

I am having a weird error and I am sure it is something very simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on. I thought I was opening and closing the forms properly, but it appears something is amiss. I am working with VS 2015.  I have my program set to close when the last form is closed. There are two forms that I am using right now.

Dashboard

```
Public Class frmDashboard
    Private Sub recExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles recExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub recMember_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles recMember.Click, lblMember.Click

        'Create instance of Member Form
        Dim memberForm As New frmMember

        'Open an instance
        memberForm.Show()

        Me.Close()

        'Using this code test if the form window is still open
        For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
            MessageBox.Show(frm.Name)
        Next


    End Sub
End Class
```

Members Form

```
Public Class frmMember

    Private Sub frmMember_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ShowSpouse(rdoMarried.Checked)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowSpouse(ByRef isMarried As Boolean)

        If isMarried Then
            'Marital status is set to married lets show the extra spouse information

            'Lets first make the form larger
            Me.Size = New Size(793, 576)

            'Now lets unhide the form
            pnlSpouse.Visible = True
            'pnlSpouse.Enabled = True

            lblSpouse.Visible = True
            'lblSpouse.Enabled = True

            lineSpouse.Visible = True
            'lineSpouse.Enabled = True

            'Now lets move the buttons to their new location
            btnApply.Location = New Point(624, 541)
            btnExit.Location = New Point(710, 541)

        Else 
            'Single is Selected
            'Let's make sure all the spouse information is hidden

            'Lets first make the form smaller
            Me.Size = New Size(793, 358)

            'Now lets hide the form and disable the controls
            pnlSpouse.Visible = False
            'pnlSpouse.Enabled = False

            lblSpouse.Visible = False
            'lblSpouse.Enabled = False

            lineSpouse.Visible = False
            'lineSpouse.Enabled = False

            'Now lets move the buttons to their new location
            btnApply.Location = New Point(624, 320)
            btnExit.Location = New Point(710, 320)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub MaritalStatusChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoSingle.CheckedChanged, rdoMarried.CheckedChanged
        ShowSpouse(rdoMarried.Checked)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

        Dim dashboard As New frmDashboard 
        'Open the dashboard
        dashboard.Show()

        'Close the member form
        Me.Close()



    End Sub
End Class
```

I havent added the database to it but eventually I will load data into the members form.  When I click to open the members form it goes through and runs the code in the form load event for members form but then returns focus back to the dashboard form. Runs the Me.Close on the dashboard, but once it gets to End Sub thats when this exception gets thrown:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

Any help you guys can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `recMember_Click()`, use `frmMember.Show()` without New and `Me.Hide()`. In `btnExit_Click()`, `frmDashboard .Show()`, without New, then `Me.Close()`

Comment: @Jimi That allowed me to open the frmMember without the exception being thrown.  When I click the recExit then it throws the exception when the Me.Close() is called for the dashboard form. Do you think this has anything to do with me using RectangleShapes as buttons?

Comment: You don't have to close the MainForm. Just hide it if you don't want it to be seen.

Comment: When I click the recExit to close the program it throws the exception still.

Comment: There's no reason for this to happen if you don't have any "new something" anywhere and nothing "newed" is ever disposed. VB.net is not C#. Also, I'm assumind that `frmDashboard` is the Main Form.

Comment: Yeah I took out all the New references in the code and it only throws the exception when I click Exit to close the application

Comment: Then you still have something that tries to dispose an already disposed object. Take a closer look at your code (something like the `MessageBox.Show(frm.Name)` is a good candidate, if you want to mess things up).

Comment: Ok, so when I use a regular button instead of a rectangleShape, I do not get the exception.